# Special Characters are not being saved in database

Tags: java, mysql

I am inserting string with special character but showing question mark("?")

code-

```
  String mainquery = "INSERT INTO thread_pitch_gauge ( nominal_value, ob1, ob2) VALUES(?,?,?)";
                    String n1 = 56°± 116’;
                    String n2 = 56° 16’ 44’’;
                    String n3 = 56° 16’ 45’’;                   
                    ps = (PreparedStatement) connection.prepareStatement(mainquery);
                    ps.setInt(1, n1);
                    ps.setString(2, n2);
                    ps.setString(3, n3);                                    
                    ps.execute();
                     ps.close();
in database value showing like
nominal_value=56°± 116’
ob1=56° 16’ 44’’
ob2=56° 16? 45?;
```

i database table all field type is varchar(50)
i getting this problem in java
database is mysql
please help me
thanks in advance

Comment: what has this got to do with Java?  Show the schema for your table

Comment: @Scary Wombat when i am inserting query directly on mysqlbrowser it inserts correctly but in java  it is not correctly inserts in database table all fields are same i.e. varachar(50)

Comment: what kind of special characters are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape special characters before inserting into the database

> There are a number of special characters that needs to be escaped
>   (protected), if you want to include them in a character string. Here
>   are some basic character escaping rules:

Here are some examples of how to include special characters:

```
SELECT 'It''s Sunday!' FROM DUAL;
It's Sunday! 

SELECT 'Allo, C\'est moi.' FROM DUAL;
Allo, C'est moi.

SELECT 'Mon\tTue\tWed\tThu\tFri' FROM DUAL;
   Mon   Tue     Wed     Thu     Fri
```

http://dba.fyicenter.com/faq/mysql/Escape-Special-Character.html

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO gauges (degreeValue,degreeValue1,degreeValue2) VALUES("56° 16’ 44’","56° 16’ 45’","56° 16’ 46'");

SELECT * FROM gauges;
```

Result  :

```
56° 16’ 44’ 
56° 16’ 45’ 
56° 16’ 46'
```

Insert Your values in "" (Double Quote)directly